# Change RENDERER_CLASS in some methods

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How can I change RENDERER_CLASS in given method to `rest_framework_csv.renderers.CSVRenderer`? I need to return text/csv in some methods.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def resources(request):
    """
    Return all public Resources.
    """
    resource_list = Resource.objects.filter(status='Public')

    data = ResourceSerializer(resource_list, many=True).data

    return Response(data)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `renderer_classes` decorator on your view.

```
from rest_framework_csv.renderers import CSVRenderer

@api_view(['GET'])
@renderer_classes((CSVRenderer,))
def resources(request):
   """
   Return all public Resources.
   """
   ...
```

See the Django Rest Framework docs on [renderers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/) for more info.